# HttpWebRequests slowing down, or timing out

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, networking

**Introduction**

I'm making an application that crawls files/websites for proxy ips/ports. The implementation is purely asynchronous, to make it flow with the speed I want. The whole purpose of the application is to find proxies that's "alive".

To check whether a proxy is alive, I'm making a `HttpWebRequest` to a specific website, and if successful it's alive, if not then dead.

**The Problem**

An example:

First run:

1. Crawls a text file with 30k proxies.
2. Makes a `HttpWebRequest` with each proxy, to check if it's "alive".
3. Finds 30 proxies that's alive.

Second run:

1. Crawls the same text file with 30k proxies.
2. Makes a `HttpWebRequest` with each proxy, to check if it's "alive".
3. Finds 0 proxies that's alive.

If I wait approx 10min, then the second run will produce ~30 proxies that's alive too. Else it will simply timeout on them, and mark them as dead.

As you probably already have figured out, my question is why the second run doesn't produce the same or close to the result of the first run.

I've changed following:

`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue`, and `ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints = int.MaxValue`

Is this a basic limitation of my network, or is something else playing in?

Comment: What are the results if you use a 3rd/4th/5th/... request? Does the problem fix itself of deteriorate into a hand/port exception?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that you are closing the first web request?

Comment: All web requests etc. are done using the dispose pattern. - Also the first run and second run in this case, refers to opening a console app, close it, and then open it again.

Comment: How long is it until the behaviour resets? You may be falling foul of a socket timeout. If the 'keep alive' flag set on your requests?

Comment: I haven't been able to measure the exact time, but approx 10min - and it works again.

Comment: No.. primarily because I've got no idea, what to change.

Comment: My first suggestion is a different router / turn off firewall. . It may be shutting you down. Perhaps try DMZ host. Sounds very much like a system problem.

Have you tried explicitly shutting down the socket underlying the web request? I dont like relying on the dispose pattern for these things. See: inconsistency in disposing readers and streams.